# d3 line chart runs off the chart when threshold values are applied

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3 and working with line chart, where i want to view the chart between the threshold values [`Fiddler`](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenuics/vxo1qsf9/). The chart works fine with y.domain([min,max]), since i want to view the chart with my own threshold values the line runs off the chart, i've no idea why this is happening. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid the lines bleeding over the graph area, what you might want is using a `clip-path`. I tweaked your code a little bit and added the clip path to it.

```
svg.append("clipPath")
   .attr("id", "clip-path")
   .append("rect")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);

svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
   .attr("d", valueline(data))
   .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-path)");
```

Here is the JSFiddle link for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/vxo1qsf9/2/

---

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get a broken graph is that, the values after 26 April is less than `75` which is the minimum you have defined. So the graph is actually drawing, but you can't see the lines because it is below the svg area you defined.

Here is my 2 cents.

- Just update the data with correct values. So that you can view the data at the end.

  ```
  {  
      date: "1-May-12",  
      close: "90.13"  
  }
  ```

  or
- Just update the `min` value to the minimum expected value.

  ```
  var thresholdValues = {
      minValue: 50,
      maxValue: 100
  };
  ```

This is what I did and seems it works fine. Here is the fiddle link for the same http://jsfiddle.net/vxo1qsf9/1/

---

If you want to automatically find the minimum and maximum value from data, use d3's native function `d3.extent()`, which returns an array containing `min` and `max` value of that array or you can also try finding  min and max separately by using `d3.min()` and `d3.max()`.

[Here](https://github.com/d3/d3-array) is the documentation link for d3 array methods.

---

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thank you for taking time out on this issue and for suggestion link on how to find min and max values. Data array and threshold values will be from API i cannot change it. As mentioned in the question i want to view the graph which is between the threshold values, is it something with path that generated or svg area?

Comment: @praveenuics So do you want to clip off the lines that are not between the chart area? If yes, read about using clip path. That might help. :D